# Sound doesn't work after migrating archlinux32 to new hardware

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa, 32bit

After changing a hardware and booting up same operating system([archlinux32](https://archlinux32.org/)) on it the sound doesn't work at all. On old hardware it worked well.

When migrated:

1. Booted up a live ISO
2. Ran `mkinitcpio -p linux`
3. Updated /etc/fstab
4. Reinstalled grub

After booting everything works fine except sound.
Also pulseaudio and alsa-utils are installed.

---

`speaker-test -c 2 -D default`:

```
speaker-test 1.1.8

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

---

`lspci -nn | grep Audio`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller [8086:2668] (rev 03)
```

---

`pactl list sinks`:

```
Sink #0
        State: IDLE
        Name: auto_null
        Description: Dummy Output
        Driver: module-null-sink.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 15
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: auto_null.monitor
        Latency: 658477 usec, configured 2000000 usec
        Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY
        Properties:
                device.description = "Dummy Output"
                device.class = "abstract"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card"
        Formats:
                pcm
```

---

`aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
```

---

`lsmod | grep snd`:

```
snd_hda_codec_realtek   102400  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          40960  0
snd_hda_codec         118784  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           73728  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
snd                    73728  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

---

`systemctl --user status pulseaudio.socket`:

```
* pulseaudio.socket - Sound System
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-03-17 21:09:12 EET; 14min ago
   Listen: /run/user/1000/pulse/native (Stream)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/pulseaudio.socket

Mar 17 21:09:12 ninmach systemd[381]: Listening on Sound System.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

---

`alsamixer`:

[image: img2]

---

`alsamixer` with chosen **HDA Intel** card:

[image: img3]

---

`alsamixer` with pressed **F5**:

[image: img4]

---

`pavucontrol`:

[image: img1]

---

`pavucontrol` with **Configuration** tab:

[image: img5]

All in all, why could it doesn't show Master or such in alsamixer and doesn't work at all.

This is an old `Foxconn 915A03-G-8KS` motheboard with single cored `Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2.66GHz` CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Some good person on **IRC** channel `#archlinux32` helped telling that a solution might be an **option** for `snd-hda-intel` kernel module: `model=6stack` or `model=6stack-digout`.

So, after reloading this module with option everything worked:

```
modprobe -r snd-hda-intel
modprobe snd-hda-intel model=6stack
```

This might be a bug in kernel, so it loads this module without a proper option and, also, a [patch](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c#L1431) doesn't work for that motherboard.

Although, adding this option manually to `/etc/modprobe.d/` will tell system to load this module with this option every next boot:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=6stack" >> /etc/modprobe.d/sound_fix.conf
```